# Markov Chain - finding $P^{n}$ from graph

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

given the following graph
[image]

I was tasked with finding $P^{(n)}$, my initial instinct was to find $P$, which i had.
$$P =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\\tfrac{1}{6} & \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
afterwards I was wondering if there’s a good method for finding $P^{(n)}$ other than multiplying $P$ by itself and trying to notice a pattern. 
Solution: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by a "good" method.  One that works here? Or one that may be useful in some other cases? Or one which can always be applied?

Looking at the graph, you never leave states $1$ or $3$, while you stay in state $2$ with probability $\frac12$ at each step and when you leave you are twice as likely to go to state $3$ as to state $1$.  So:

- You never leave state $1$ so the first row of $P^n$ must be: $\quad 1 \quad \quad 0 \quad \quad 0$
- You stay in state $2$ after $n$ steps with probability $\frac1{2^n}$, so leave at at some stage with probability $1-\frac1{2^n}$, and if you leave then the conditional probability of going to state $1$ (and staying there) is $\frac13$ and of going to state $3$ (and staying there) is $\frac23$, so the second row of $P^n$ must be: $\quad \frac13\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right) \quad \frac1{2^n} \quad  \frac23\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)$
- You never leave state $3$ so the third row of $P^n$ must be: $\quad 0 \quad \quad 0 \quad \quad 1$

Comment: By good  i mean a method so that if I ever end up seeing this or a variation of this kind of question on a test I'd have an algorithm

Comment: Amazing method - thank you!

Comment: If you know some random signals, can you please have a look at the questions I've asked in the signal processing stackexchange?